Pelican SSG - adding directory to URL
I'm trying to add the relative directory to the URL. So assuming the following structure of my content:
- /pages
|- about.md
|- /events
 |-- conference.md

I would like to have two pages: /about and /events/conference
I tried to use the USE_FOLDER_AS_CATEGORY setting but it doesn't work: all my pages are generated under urls without the directory/category (/about and /conference), even though in the output the directory structure is preserved (I've got output/about/index.html and output/events/conference/index.html. Why it doesn't work? What am I missing? Here is the pelicanconf.py:
USE_FOLDER_AS_CATEGORY = True

PAGE_PATHS = ['pages']
PAGE_URL = '{category}/{slug}/'
PAGE_SAVE_AS = '{category}/{slug}/index.html'
PAGE_TEMPLATE = 'page'

